# SpecFlow LivingDoc throwing syntax error when generated on Azure Hosted Agents

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, specflow

We are currently using the LivingDoc CLI tool to generate our .html report in an Azure DevOps release pipeline. We don't want to use the Azure DevOps plugin because it doesn't retain historical results, so what we're doing is running our tests, generating the .html file as part of a task in the release, moving it to a blob and generating a URL against the test run so people can view the results.

When we run this on our local machines it works fine, but when we run it on a hosted agent, we get a syntax error.

[image: Console Log]

I've done some digging in the .html file itself, and it looks like what is happening is in the local one, multiple locale configurations that have special characters (such as say, Arabic) are put in the file correctly as per the below screenshot.

[image: Local file html]

However, when running on a hosted agent, these characters are not present.

[image: Blob file html]

We are using the latest version of the CLI tool and the .nuget package in our solution. Has anyone else had this issue and managed to resolve it? Specifying the project language as a parameter didn't help, and we're at a loss at what to do here.

Comment: What is the mime-type for these files? Do they include a character set? Maybe this is a config issue on the server. Default character set, maybe?